# Why isn't ActiveRecord's autosave working on my association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord class that looks something like this.

```
class Foo
  belongs_to :bar, autosave: true
  before_save :modify_bar
  ...
end
```

If I do some logging, I see that the `bar` is being modified, but its changes are not saved. What's wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem here is that `autosave: true` simply sets up a normal `before_save` callback, and `before_save` callbacks are run in the order that they're created.**

Therefore, it tries to save the `bar`, which has no changes, **then** it calls `modify_bar`.

The solution is to ensure that the `modify_bar` callback runs before the autosave.

One way to do that is with the `prepend` option.

```
class Foo
  belongs_to :bar, autosave: true
  before_save :modify_bar, prepend: true
  ...
end
```

Another way would be to put the `before_save` statement before the `belongs_to`.

Another way would be to explicitly save `bar` at the end of the `modify_bar` method and not use the `autosave` option at all.

Thanks to Danny Burkes for the [helpful blog post](http://pivotallabs.com/activerecord-callbacks-autosave-before-this-and-that-etc).

** Also, they're run after all `after_validation` callbacks and before any `before_create` callbacks - [see the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

---

### Update

Here's one way to check the order of such callbacks.

```
  describe "sequence of callbacks" do

    let(:sequence_checker) { SequenceChecker.new }

    before :each do
      foo.stub(:bar).and_return(sequence_checker)
    end

    it "modifies bar before saving it" do
      # Run the before_save callbacks and halt before actually saving
      foo.run_callbacks(:save) { false }
      # Test one of the following
      #
      # If only these methods should have been called
      expect(sequence_checker.called_methods).to eq(%w[modify save])
      # If there may be other methods called in between
      expect(sequence_checker.received_in_order?('modify', 'save')).to be_true
    end

  end
```

Using this supporting class:

```
class SequenceChecker
  attr_accessor :called_methods

  def initialize
    self.called_methods = []
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    called_methods << method_name.to_s
  end

  def received_in_order?(*expected_methods)
    expected_methods.map!(&:to_s)
    called_methods & expected_methods == expected_methods
  end

end
```

Comment: By the way, Danny mentioned that `auto_save: true` is the default for `belongs_to` relationships; I just made it explicit here for the sake of a clear example.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is (clearly) your solution. However:

I am fine using `:autosave`, but I don't think changing external associations is a job for callbacks.  I'm talking about your `:modify_bar`.  As brilliantly explained [in this post](http://samuelmullen.com/2013/05/the-problem-with-rails-callbacks) *I prefer to use another object* to save multiple models at once.  It really simplifies your life when things get more complex and makes tests much easier.

In this situation this might be accomplished in the controller or from a service object.